# Executing get-pip.py in any terminal outputs nothing

Tags: python, pip

On my new computer(Windows 10, I mean duh.) Just like how everyone does and how I did on my other computer, I ran

```
python get-pip.py
```

after installing get-pip.py by typing

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.p
```

in the cmd

I have checked the path and the location of my file. However, nothing gets output. Not even an error. It just proceeds to a new line.
I am doing this exactly how I did it on my last computer so I cannot really find anything else wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.p
```

should be

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```